# List of Products from an API

Tags: arrays, react-native, api

For my app, I am using an API that contains sales order history.
The returned array looks like this, I take an example of an order with 2 products :

```
Object {
    "amount": 2671.25,
    "balance": 0,
    "client_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-05-06T17:42:26Z",
    "discount": 0,
    "discount_type": 0,
    "id": 19,
    "items": Array [
      Object {
        "cost": 2400,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "description": "blablabla",
        "name": "Apple MacBook Air 15'' LED 500 Go SSD 32 Go",
        "product_id": 5,
        "quantity": 1,
        "tax_rate_id": 1,
      },
      Object {
        "cost": 54.25,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "description": "Blablabla",
        "product_id": 2,
        "quantity": 5,
        "tax_rate_id": 4,
      },
    ],
    "po_number": "",
    "public_notes": "TEST 6 : Acomptes",
    "quote_date": "2020-05-06",
    "quote_number": "D1460019",
    "quote_status": 40,
    "terms": "",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-06T18:08:06Z",
  },
```

Currently on my screen, I return the date of the order in 'title' with a drop-down menu where I have the total price of the order. It works, I use this code:

```
<ScrollView>
      {
        this.state.displayArray.map((item, i) => (
        <List.Section title={item.created_at} key={i.toString()}>
          <List.Accordion
            title={item.id}
            left={props => <List.Icon {...props} icon="cart" />}>
            <List.Item title={`${item.amount} €`}/>
          </List.Accordion>     
        </List.Section>
        ))
      }
      </ScrollView>
```

But now, I would like to make this screen a little more complex. I would like to add to the drop-down menu the number of items and the name + price of the items (wholesale, have the detail of the order)

My problem is that I don't know how to extract the products from the array. If I do

> <List.Item title = {`$ {item.items.name}} />

it won't work since there are two objects with two different names in the array ... (i tried and it returns 'undefined')

I'm not sure how to do it.
I know my English is not perfect, I don't know if my explanations are clear. Basically there, I only have the price below my order and I will like with the details of the products with their respective prices.

---------------------------- EDIT TO ADD SOLUTION -------------------------------

Thank you @HichamELBSI

```
<ScrollView>
      {
        this.state.displayArray.map((item, i) => (
        <List.Section title={item.created_at} key={i.toString()}>
          <List.Accordion
            title={item.id}
            left={props => <List.Icon {...props} icon="cart" />}>
            <List.Item title={`${item.amount} €`}/>
            {
              item.items.map((product, i) => (
              <List.Item title={product.name} key={i.toString()}/>
              ))
            }
          </List.Accordion>            
        </List.Section>
        ))
      }
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can map the products like what you do for the display.

```js
<ScrollView>
      {
        this.state.displayArray.map((item, i) => (
        <List.Section title={item.created_at} key={i.toString()}>
          <List.Accordion
            title={item.id}
            left={props => <List.Icon {...props} icon="cart" />}>
            <List.Item title={`${item.amount} €`}/>
          </List.Accordion>
          {item.items.map(product => (
             <List.Item title={product.name} />
           )}} 
        </List.Section>
        ))
      }
</ScrollView>
```

Let me know if that is what you need

Comment: I used your code and readjusted it slightly and it works !!! THANK YOU !!! Thank you very sincerely! I allow myself to edit my post to add the exact solution.